# highlight table row containing a word and export to excel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using this jQuery script to highlight rows in html table. It works all fine but when I export that table in excel, all the rows of excel gets that formating, even the part outside of table. I have also pasted the export script.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVhn8.png)

```
$("#X tr:contains(' Total')").css("background-color", "Gainsboro");
$("#X tr:contains(' Total')").css("font-weight", "bold");
$("#X tr:contains('Grand Total')").css("background-color", "yellow");
$("#X tr:contains('Grand Total')").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns: <head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x: <x: <x: <x: {worksheet}</x: <x: <x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x: ExcelWorksheet ></x: ExcelWorksheets ></x: ExcelWorkbook ></xml >< ![endif]-- ></head > <body><table>{table}</table></body></html > '
  , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
  , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function (table, name) {
  if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
  var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
  window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})();
</script>
```

Comment: you don't want formatting in excel?

Comment: Yes I do, pls see the screenshot attached. The highlight goes outside the table, looks bad.